# Make function takes both Range and RangeInclusive

Tags: rust, range

I want a function that takes Range as it's argument.

```rust
fn takes_range(range: Range<i32>) {
    // DO SOMETING WITH RANGE
}
```

I can use this function like,

```rust
takes_range(0..5);
```

but not

```rust
takes_range(0..=5);
```

I realized that there are two types named Range and RangeInclusive.
So if I want to takes inclusive range, should make two functions.

```rust
fn takes_range(Range<i32>) {}
fn takes_range_inclusive(RangeInclusive<i32>) {}
```

However this is not I want. I want to takes both Range and RangeInclusive, so I can use

```rust
takes_range(0..5);
takes_range(0..=5);
```

Is it possible to make my function takes both of these types?

Comment: See https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [`RangeBounds`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html) trait that is implemented for all the [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html#structs) types. So you can make your function generic with that trait as a constraint:

```
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

fn takes_range<R: RangeBounds<i32>>(range: R) {
    // ...
}
```

However, whether this actually does what you want depends on what the *"do something with range"* is. Rust generics only have access to what they're constrained, so this only lets you query the range's start, end, and if a value is contained in it. If you for example wanted to use it in a `for` loop, you'd need to constrain on `IntoIterator<Item = i32>` as well.